# Xamarin android download hangs after second try

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, polly

I am really struggling with the following piece of code.
Currently working on a Xamarin Android App.
I am downloading a file from a webserver, but in case of a network outage, i want to retry the download a few times. But after the second time an exception is thrown, it doesn't continue the download anymore.
The first time it works like a charm.

I have also tried it without the use of Polly, and tried it recursively with some delay built in. But no luck. After the exception has been thrown the download doesn't continue anymore.
:-( any idea what is causing this?
Something built into Android 9.0?

```cs
await Policy
    .Handle<NetworkOnMainThreadException>()
    .Or<Java.Net.UnknownHostException>()
    .Or<SSLException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    })
    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        totalRead = await DownloadFile(url, progress, totalRead, token);

    });
```

Here are the `DownloadFile` and `OpenStream` functions

```cs
private async Task<long> DownloadFile(string url, IProgress<double> progress, long totalRead, CancellationToken token)
{
    // Step 1 : Get call using HttpClient
    var response = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("The request returned with HTTP status code {0}", response.StatusCode));
    }

    // Step 2 : Filename
    var fileName = url.Split('/').Last();

    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Step 3 : Get total of data
    var totalData = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault(-1L);

    // Step 4 : Get the full path
    var filePath = Path.Combine(_fileService.GetStorageFolderPath(), fileName);

    // Step 5 : Download data
    using (var fileStream = OpenStream(filePath, totalRead))
    {
        using (var inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                totalRead += bytesRead;

                // Write data on disk.
                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                progress.Report((totalRead * 1d) / (totalData * 1d) * 100);
            }
            progress.Report(0);
        }
    }

    return totalRead;
}

private Stream OpenStream(string path, long totalRead)
{
    if (totalRead > 0)
    {
        return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize);
    }
    else
    {
        return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mention "an exception" twice without providing any specific detail about what the exception is or which line causes it

Comment: the exceptions that are thrown during the download are the ones I mention in the code and I simulate a network outage with the android emulator

Comment: that's three possible exceptions - does it throw all three?  Or just one?  What is the stack trace?

Comment: what happens in Polly is that the DownloadFile function executes and the DownloadFile function can throw three possible exception (NetworkOnMainThreadException, UnknownHostException or SSLException). Not all three at once. Then Polly catches these exception if one of them appear and ignores them. Because there the result of the network outage. And it tries the DownloadFile function again

Comment: I added the complete download file function

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this: *it doesn't continue the download anymore*? Does  the policy not trigger? Does it throw an exception? Does it hang indefinitely?  or???